# Problem with set value in view and template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a list where the user can give titles to his list in which he selects in which category he should be, this is how the model looks like

```
class UserListAnime(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    anime = models.ManyToManyField(Anime, through='ListAnime')


class Anime(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = extension_fields.AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', blank=True)


class ListAnime(models.Model):

LIST_CHOICES = (
        (WATCHING, 'Oglądam'),
        (PLANNING, 'Planuję'),
        (COMPLETED, 'Ukończone'),
        (DROPPED, 'Porzucone'),
        (ONHOLD, 'Wstrzymane'),
        (MISSING, 'Pomijam'),
    )

user = models.ForeignKey(UserListAnime, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    anime = models.ForeignKey(Anime, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=LIST_CHOICES, null=False, blank=False)
```

In the view I only have to take a list of the user and I have displayed it but I want it to be filtered through the type in `ListAnime`

```
def ListAnimeView(request, pk, username):
    list_anime = UserListAnime.objects.filter(user__pk=pk, user__username=username,
                                           listanime__type='ogladam',
                                           anime__listanime__type='ogladam').all()
    context = locals()
```

and html looks like

```
{% for list in list_anime.anime.all %}
    {{ list }}
{% endfor %}
```

My question is how to extract all records when type = LIST_CHOICES and show this in html

EDIT: SOLVED just need change in view from `UserListAnime,objects..` to `ListAnime.objects`
and in html should be

```
{% for list in list_anime %}
    {{ list.anime }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "when type = LIST_CHOICES"?

Comment: i mean "type = one from the list" example like in code above, but it does not work, or I wrote badly in html, so I wanted to ask for a hint about what is wrong and how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to get a list of `ListAnime` entities given a user, and get only which are of type 'ogladam'?

```
def listAnimeView(request, pk):
    list_anime = ListAnime.objects.filter(user__user_id=pk, type='ogladam')
    return render(request, 'template-name', context=['list_anime': list_anime])'
```

Comment: I was do something like that in the same time, thanks :)